# מחויאל and מחייאל Bereshis perek 4:18

Tags: names, parashat-bereishit, text

Why did the pasuk change מחויאל to מחייאל in Bereshis 4:18? Is there any peirush who discusses this change and it significance?

Comment: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/admur/lkus/35/8/1/137

Comment: He became chassidish!

Comment: @doubleaa I  see you are in Purim mode already

Answer (score 2):

An explanation is given by [Radak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34563&st=&pgnum=38&hilite=) in which he notices that change and mentions the fact that in ancient times it was a custom to parents to rename their children according to certain events in their lives; sometimes a reason is presented, sometimes not.

According to [Bereshis Rabbah 23:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%92_%D7%91) (also [Yalkut Shimoni Iyov 918](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=30&perek=30&mefaresh=shimoni)) this change might had happened due to rebellious behavior:

> ויולד לחנוך את עירד וגו' - אמר רבי יהושע בן לוי: כולן לשון מרדות הן.
>   עירד, עורדן אני מן העולם. **מחויאל, מוחן אני מן העולם**
>
> Said Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi: All these names signify chastening: Irad,
>   "I shall drive them out of the world" (through the *mabul*);
>   Mehujael, "I will wipe them from the world".